# Circular reference in ASP.NET Web API and Entity Framework Code First when using many-to-many relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I have two Entity Framework entities that share a many-to-many (n:n) relationship as follows:

- `A` has many `B`
- `B` has many `A`

```cs
public partial class A
{

    public A()
    {
        this.Cs= new HashSet<C>();
        this.Bs= new HashSet<B>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public D D { get; set; }
    public long DId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<C> Cs { get; set; }
    public ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public partial class B
{
    public B()
    {
        this.Es= new HashSet<E>();
        this.As = new HashSet<A>();
    }
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long DId { get; set; }
    public D D { get; set; }

    public ICollection<E> Es { get; set; }
    public ICollection<A> As { get; set; }
}
```

My global configuration is configured to ignore reference loops:

```cs
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        JsonMediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        var jSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
            DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
        };

        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = jSettings;
    }

}
```

Last but not least, all of my data contexts are configured to not use either lazy loading nor proxy creation:

```cs
public AController()
{
    db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

When it comes to one-to-many (1:n) or one-to-one (1:1) relationships, I have no problem. If I need to fetch the children or the parent, a simple `Include` does the trick. When I don't need those, the object comes clean with empty arrays or objects on the relationships.

The problem occurs when I have a many-to-many (n:n) relationship, the system seems to fail to realize that it is a recurrence and I either get a very large object graph, or I get a memory overflow.

In the given object example, I am simply doing:

```cs
var ret = db.ASet.Include(x => x.Cs).Include(x => x.Bs).Where(x => x.Id > 1345);
```

This returns to me an array of `A`, that has an array of `B`, which has an array of `E` and `A`, and those `A`'s have an array of `B` and so on.

If you know how I can make it truly ignore this relationship, it will help me a lot. But as far as I have found, it seems to be a bug in Entity Framework.

Comment: Does the issue occur when you materialize the results, or when you go to serialize them?  In general, a circular reference in entity framework is not an issue because of the identity map maintained by the EF context (e.g. there's only one instance of A and B in your example).

Comment: The problem is on the webapi serialization, and if i do a Json(object) on the mvc controller as well.